# Parallel Flux vs Flux in project Reactor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So what I have understood from the docs is that parallel Flux is that essentially divided the flux elements into separate rails.(Essentially something like grouping). And as far as thread is considered, it would be the job of schedulers. So let's consider a situation like this. And all this will be run on the same scheduler instance provided via runOn() methods.
Let's consider a situation like below:

```
Mono<Response> = webClientCallAPi(..) //function returning Mono from webclient call
```

Now let's say we make around 100 calls

```
Flux.range(0,100).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).flatMap(i -> webClientCallApi(i)).collecttoList() // or subscribe somehow
```

and if we use paralleFlux:

```
Flux.range(0,100).parallel().runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).flatMap(i -> webClientCallApi(i)).sequential().collecttoList();
```

So if my understanding is correct, it pretty much seems to be similar. So what are the advantages of ParallelFlux over Flux and when should you use parallelFlux over flux?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In practice, you'll likely very rarely need to use a parallel flux, including in this example.

In your example, you're firing off 100 web service calls. Bear in mind the actual *work* needed to do this is very low - you generate and fire off an asynchronous request, and then some time later you receive a response back. In between that request & response you're not doing any work at all, it simply takes a *tiny* amount of CPU resources when each request is sent, and another *tiny* about when each response is received. (This is one of the core advantages of using an asynchronous framework to make your web requests, you're not tying up any threads while the request is in-flight.)

If you split this flux and run it in parallel, you're saying that you want these tiny amounts of CPU resources to be split so they can run simultaneously, on different CPU cores. This makes absolutely no sense - the overhead of splitting the flux, running it in parallel and then combining it later is going to be much, much greater than just leaving it to execute on a normal, sequential scheduler.

On the other hand, let's say I had a `Flux<Integer>` and I wanted to check if each of those integers was a prime for example - or perhaps a `Flux<String>` of passwords that I wanted to check against a BCrypt hash. Those sorts of operations are *genuinely* CPU intensive, so in that case a parallel flux, used to split execution across cores, could make a lot of sense. In reality though, those situations occur quite rarely in the normal reactor use cases.

(Also, just as a closing note, you almost always want to use `Schedulers.parallel()` with a parallel flux, not `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`.)

Comment: Totally agree that in reactor scenarios. But my point is what decides to run on parallel is the scedulers right(I mean truly creating threads and stuff like that). But if you  do something like this Flux.range(1,100).publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()), it simply assigns the things parallelly right? I mean why have an overhead of creating parallel rails(or as I call them "grouping") by introducing ParalleFlux, if this can be done via flux?

Comment: subscribeOn and publishOn uses a single thread from the specified publisher, it won't be concurrent

Comment: @DeekshithAnand "if you do something like this Flux.range(1,100).publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()), it simply assigns the things parallelly right?" - No, not at all. That can never execute flux tasks in parallel, because the underlying non-parallel flux will only supply them one at a time. The fact you see the web requests executing at the same time is not proof of parallelism (instead proof of concurrency.)

Comment: ahh.. i see there is a subtle difference between concurrency and parallelism... that clears. ty!

Comment: a very comprehensive answer, thank you